# Repeater ItemCommand does not fire when clicking a button inside composite control

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, composite-controls

I have a `Repeater` containing nested custom `CompositeControl` controls in the following way:

`Wrapper`

- `Head`
- `Body`

```cs
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="noteArea" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="noteRepeater" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" OnItemDataBound="noteRepeater_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="noteRepeater_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="edit" ID="testButton" />
                <easit:NoteControl ID="noteControl" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

`Head` control contains two `Buttons`. When I click on either of them, the `ItemCommand` event of `Repeater` doesn't get invoked. If I move the buttons right to `ItemTemplate`, it works. But I need to keep them where they are.

What is the correct way to bubble them up the control hierarchy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the control throw an event which your page (with the repeater) can listen for. Any information you need for the event can be provided when initializing each control.

Comment: Hi, I've tried to do so, but ran into another problem. The flow never reaches the event handler I've defined for button click, even though I'm binding it `OnInit` in the control containing it. I suspect it's because it's parent control creates it's control structure `OnPreRender`, but if I try to move it to `OnLoad` or `OnInit` the `Repeater` shows up empty.

Comment: That's because the button event handler would not capture that event, the page where the repeater resides would handle it. The only reason to have the button capture the event is to be able to get information about which element was clicked. As I stated in my answer, you can pass the UC any information you need to handle the event. Does that make sense?

Comment: @AlexandarŽivkovič: Thank you sir. Did it all work out for you? Any more questions?

Comment: You're welcome. In the end I got rid of the `Wrapper` control, leaving `Head` and `Body` directly inside the `ItemTemplate` and using the `ItemCommand` event to respond to clicks. Still got a lot to learn about handling `ViewState` though. Anyway, I'm most certainly thankful for your input :)

Answer (score 1):

These controls are outside the ItemTemplate .. so they really can't trigger an ItemCommand.

An ItemCommand has specific attributes that will not be available to your buttons if they are outside the ItemTemplate (ItemIndex for instance, to determine the index of the clicked item)

Comment: But the `Wrapper` control is defined within `ItemTemplate`. Does it still mean that it's child controls are outside of it?